# Any implementation of an Unrolled Linked List in C#?

Tags: c#, clr, pinvoke, linked-list

I'm interested in using an "[unrolled linked list](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devdev/archive/2005/08/22/454887.aspx)" in my C# application.

Is anyone aware of a stable implementation, especially one that will allow me to configure how much padding to allocate per array?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the 2nd comment in your own link, such a list should be implemented in [BigList in the PowerCollections library](http://powercollections.codeplex.com/). It's open source, so you could have a look at the code and see if it allows for your scenario, or if it can be adapted to fit your needs easily.

Other than that, I am now aware of any .NET implementations you could use.

Comment: aah, the comment didn't have a blue link so I must have skimmed over it.  Thanks!

Comment: It appears that that library is quite old, and is mostly obsolete. I hope Microsoft would add this to the core framework.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/megatherion/Unrolled-linked-list) you can find a working implementation written in Java. It can be a good starting point to write a new implementation in C#. I have tested this class and it is many times faster than the standard LinkedList class in Java.